# A contractible space which is not a H-space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there some example of a contractible space which no admit a multiplication with strict unit?

Comment: What about any closed interval in the real line?

Comment: This is homeomorphic to the unit interval [0,1] which has a multiplication with unit. Via the homeomorphism you can transfer the multiplication to your preferred interval.

Comment: Yes, that is the right link. That question is closely related to my question on strict and homotopy units in Ainfty spaces. Your answer there was really good but the your link were wrong. Thank you.

Comment: This present question is closely...

Comment: I believe K. Borsuk's "dunce hat" is one of the simplest examples of a space you are asking for; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)

Comment: I think not, since the dunce hat is contractible, it is a WU-space (by Bordman-Vogt' homotopy transfer principle) and then, in particular, it has a homotopy unital multiplication. However, the dunce hat is a CW complex and then the homotopy unit can be rectifyied in a strict one.